# will signing the title of a car release ownership solely to the co owner

Tags: title

I am trying to take a loan against my paid for car, however my ex's name is also on the title. he signed the back of the title relinquishing any claim or ownership of the vehicle. will that be sufficient to get a new title with my as the only owner. Unfortunately the situation is volatile and unsafe for me to contact him to have him go to the dmv with me.

Comment: What country/state are you?

Comment: This does depend on jurisdiction. In some places signing over the title is sufficient. I have lined places where it isn't, and you have to go to the Department of Motor Vehicles (or equivalent) and pay the fee to have a new title issued with that change. Whether he would have to go with you may also depend on where the car is registered. Your DMV probably has documents which describe the correct process; these days the information may even be on their website.